# Using MediaPlayer Object To Stream RTSP THROW EXCEPTION Prepared fail

Tags: android, exception, stream, rtsp

i read almost all the post before and still can't handle it.

i just can't understand -> in the android developers pages it written that mediaplayer support rtsp but still i can't able to stream any rtsp to media player witout it throw an exception. i'm not using Emulator but galaxy s2 also i checked the link in vlc on my device and my mac... and it play. so what is the problem, according to android developers pages all i need to do is setDataSource then prepare and then start.

anyone encounter this problem? is there any solution except then build my own connection\mediaplayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your videos were properly encoded for Android playback. See [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).